# sparse matrix alignment

Tags: java, matrix, alignment, sparse-matrix

is there any way to align these values in my sparse matrix?

```
0  0  0  0 8 2 

0  0  0 19 11  0 

0 11  0 13  0  0 

0 18  0  0 7  0 

0  0  0  0 4  0 

0  0 3  0  0  0
```

at the moment i have this:

```
if (matrix[i][j] < 20)
System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
else
System.out.print(" " + 0 + " ");
```

the problem i'm having is if the value is between 1 and 9 then no space is left before the value and therefore messes up my alignment. i could insert another if statement, but was wondering if theres an easier/cleaner way of doing this?

any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Check out what `String.format` can do for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was solving the similar task while working on [la4j](http://la4j.org) (Linear Algebra for Java). The la4j uses overriden `toString()` method for this needs. So, I decided to use slow (since the console output is using primary in debug mode and la4j has fast and effective streams for release versions) but safe algorithm. Here is the code (the `precision` is number of digits after delimiter):

```
@Override
public String toString() {

    final int precision = 3; 

    int formats[] = new int[columns];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            long value = (long) unsafe_get(i, j);
            int size = Long.toString(value).length() + precision + 2;
            formats[j] = size > formats[j] ? size : formats[j];
        }
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            sb.append(String.format("%" + Integer.toString(formats[j])
                    + "." + precision + "f", unsafe_get(i, j)));
        }
        sb.append("\n");
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

So, there are two steps in algorithm:

1. Calculate `formats` array as number of charachers that needs to
   print `i` colomn aligned
2. Print matrix